# Determining average rainfall for cumulative watershed, where only sub-watersheds defined?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics, arc-hydro, precipitation

I have a polygon layer with sub-catchments (sub-watersheds) and a grid of rainfall.  I have used the Zonal Stats as a table to calculate the average rainfall for each sub-catchment, but I now need to get the cumulative average rainfall for each sub-catchment as I move down through the catchment.

I'm not sure how to prepare a layer with the "accumulated" sub-catchments, and then run the Zonal statistics (which would then be on overlapping polygons which I don't think it likes!)

Comment: Could you accumulate the raster using flow direction and flow accumulation and then use zonal statistics on the accumulated raster?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm a bit of a novice here - I tried your suggestion, but it doesnt allow me to use the resultant "Fac" in the zonal stats.
I'm trying to get average rainfall across each cumulative sub-catchment, if I can work out how to create polygons that represent the increasing size of the catchment as I go downstream, I should be able to use the zonal stats

Comment: Accumulating polygons in a particular direction is difficult, i've never found a satisfactory method except for manually. There could be some relationship between sub-catchments and watercourses though. The flow accumulation is a raster and should work with zonal stats, the difficult part is relating the rainfall stats with the accumulation.